# 500 internal server error when changing the db from sqlite to postgres with django and nginx

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx

I am wondering about some things, i followed this tutorials [setting up server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)
I am currently using django 2.2, psycopg2 2.8.3, uwsgi 2.0.18.
I am able to migrate models to db but the nginx server failed to communicate with it.
I added local host with port 5432 to cors header.
does this a permission issue, as nginx runs with a user? or it is something else? should i use https for local host in cors header allowed hosts as nginx and django only allow https requests?

Comment: nginx does not communicate with your db, django (python) does. If you had a working setup, changed the db from sqlite to postgres and now get 500 errors, then there is no need to change anything on the nginx config! most likely django cannot access the new db properly. have you tried to access it with `python manage.py shell` locally on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was psycopg2 wasn't installed in venv location, even when i activate venv it does't install it in the venv dir. so i copy it from the location where it was installed to venv lib/site-packages, and it worked perfectly.